# Set of pairs, with and without repetitions

Tags: tla+

I have two sets:

```
X = {a, b}
Y = {1, 2, 3}
```

I would like to generate the following set of sets of pairs:

```
{<<a, 1>>, <<a, 2>>, <<a, 3>>}
{<<a, 1>>, <<a, 2>>, <<b, 3>>}
{<<a, 1>>, <<b, 2>>, <<a, 3>>}
{<<a, 1>>, <<b, 2>>, <<b, 3>>}
...
{<<b, 1>>, <<b, 2>>, <<b, 3>>}
```

In each set the first element is from X and the second is from Y. X can be repeated, Y cannot. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `\X` operator gives us the set of all pairs: `X \X Y = {<<a, 1>>, <<a, 2>>, ... <<b, 3>>}`. `SUBSET (X \X Y)` gives us all possible sets. `{s \in SUBSET (X \X Y): Cardinality(s) = 3}` (from the FiniteSets module) gives us all 3-element sets.

We want to make this unique on the second element of each pair. Let's define a new operator:

```
UniqueBy(set, Op(_)) == Cardinality(set) = Cardinality({Op(s): s \in set})
```

If we do `{x[2] : x \in {<<a, 1>>, <<a, 2>>, <<a, 2>>}}`, we get `{1, 2}`, which has a smaller cardinality and will be filtered out. So our final expression is

```
{s \in SUBSET (X \X Y) : UniqueBy(s, LAMBDA x: x[2]) /\ Cardinality(s) = 3}
```

Note that without the cardinality check `{<<a, 1>>}` would be part of the set of sets, which isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```python
EXTENDS Functions, FiniteSets, Naturals

CONSTANTS a, b

X == {a, b}
Y == {1, 2, 3}

Dom == 1..Cardinality(Y)

Slice == {{<< xt[n], yt[n] >>:  n \in Dom}:
              << xt, yt >> \in [Dom -> X] \X Bijection(Dom, Y)}
```

The TLAPS distribution includes the module [`Functions`](https://github.com/tlaplus/v2-tlapm/blob/75149e47e31b530ba5cbc8e833570579c54daf3f/library/Functions.tla#L46). The modules [`FiniteSets`](https://github.com/tlaplus/tlaplus/blob/master/tlatools/src/tla2sany/StandardModules/FiniteSets.tla) and [`Naturals`](https://github.com/tlaplus/tlaplus/blob/master/tlatools/src/tla2sany/StandardModules/Naturals.tla) are part of the standard library of TLA+.